# Build formulas with different spectra

Tags: logic

Find a formula whose spectrum is
a){13, 17} ∪ {n | n > 2007};
b) the set of all numbers not divisible by 3;
c) the set of all powers of two.

The spectrum of the formula ϕ is the set of natural numbers
n such that there is a normal model of the formula ϕ of power n

It is clear how to build a formula for point 1: just write that there are 13 different elements and there are not 14 or there are 17 different ones but there are not 18 or there are 2007 different ones. But at points b and c, everything becomes not so obvious

Comment: What is a "normal" model? Does "power" mean cardinality? Can you use any relation or function symbols?

Comment: @Karl yes, by power I mean cardinality. It seems to me that we can take an arbitrary signature. The normal model is a model in which equality has the meaning of equality of elements

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. For (b), you can use a relation or function symbol to form 3-element groupings in the model (with one or two elements excluded). Think a permutation with 3-cycles or an equivalence relation.

Comment: For (c), I think you can set things up so that your model corresponds to the power set of a finite set $S$, using an arbitrary subset of the model to represent $S$ and a relation $R(x,y)$ stating whether the element of $S$ represented by $x$ (if any) is in the subset of $S$ represented by $y$. Maybe there's a cleaner way.

Comment: @Karl how can a subset be rebresented by some x if x is contained in few subsets? Or I just dont get the idea

Comment: Some elements will "have two jobs", one to represent a subset of $S$ and another to represent an element of $S$. Another way to think of it is that we're using $R(i,y)$ in place of $n$ unary relations $R_i(y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on my suggestion for (c):

If we had $n$ unary relations $P_1,\dots,P_n$, then there would be $2^n$ possible tuples of truth values $(P_1(x),\dots,P_n(x))$. The idea is to set up a general version of this by replacing $P_i(x)$ with $P(i,x)$ and adding a predicate $S$ that designates the $n$ valid indexes. By reading "$P(i,x)$" as "$i\in x$", we can think of each element $x$ as representing a subset of the index set (even if $x$ also happens to serve as a valid index).

The desired formula is the conjunction of the following axioms, where $\forall^S i\ \phi$ is short for $\forall i\ (S(i)\implies \phi)$:

- No two sets contain exactly the same elements (essentially [extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality)): $\forall x\ \forall y\ (\forall^Si\ P(i,x)\iff P(i,y))\implies x=y.$
- There is an empty set: $\exists x\ \forall^S i\ \lnot P(i,x).$
- For every set $x$ and every index $i$, there is a set $y$ that differs from $x$ only on index $i$: $\forall x\ \forall^Si\ \exists y\ \forall^Sj\ (P(j,y)\iff P(j,x))\iff i\ne j$.

The last two axioms ensure that every (finite) subset of the index set is represented, and the first axiom ensures that there are no more objects than sets represented. Therefore, if a model's interpretation of $S$ has (finite) cardinality $n$, then the model has cardinality $2^n$. (Infinite models are more interesting, since the axioms don't pin down which infinite subsets of $S$ are represented.)

Answer (score 0):

For c you can take the formula translating the sentence "a group in which every element has order two".

For b, take a theory with a function, say that its cube is the identity and that it has exactly one or two fixed points.